# Chai expect not reverting when it does on-chain

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chai

I'm currently writing some tests for my contract to make sure the custom errors are being reverted in the contract. Example:

```
function fund(address sender, uint256 amount) public {
      if (amount <= 0) {
           revert FundMe__FundAmountMustBeAboveZero();
      }
      doOtherStuff();
}
```

So in my test I have the following code:

```
it("fails when you fund 0 tokens", async function () {
     await expect(fundMe.fund(deployer.address, 0)).to.be.revertedWith(
          "FundAmountMustBeAboveZero"
     )
})
```

Clearly given the code this should be reverted but in the test it keeps telling me that the transaction was not reverted.

```
AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted
      + expected - actual

      -Transaction NOT reverted.
      +Transaction reverted.
```

Even if you look at the transaction on etherscan it says it reverted within the contract execution... https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x6f757bcd1aa1aa336f1fc5a71dd05ac249e175e8ee55f179c038bd4f75e2f32a

Not really sure what to do about this, if this is an error in my code or some weird bug with chai?

Answer (score 0):

to.be.revertedWith with not match with the name of a custom error.

try changing this

```
 await expect(fundMe.fund(deployer.address, 0)).to.be.revertedWith(
      "FundAmountMustBeAboveZero"
 )
```

to

```
 await expect(fundMe.fund(deployer.address, 0)).to.be.revertedWithCustomError (
          "FundMe__FundAmountMustBeAboveZero"
     )
```

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/reference

Comment: Tried that, now I'm just getting a similar error:      `AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with custom error 'FundMe__FundAmountMustBeAboveZero', but it didn't revert`

Answer (score 0):

Seems weird, but please use [Hardhat console.log](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/debugging-with-hardhat-network) and check what is in `amount`. Beside - you need to use `(...).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(fundMe, "FundMe__FundAmountMustBeAboveZero");`

Comment: The strangest thing is that it works completely fine on the local hardhat network but when running on the live testnet I get the issue described above

Comment: Try to console.log and get back to us with it please :)

Comment: I did try console.log and it gave me the expected result of zero because it is working on the local hardhat network but since console.log doesn't work on the testnet it doesn't really add any insight :/

Comment: So if you do
`function fund(address sender, uint256 amount) public {
      console.log("amount: ", amount);
      if (amount <= 0) {
           console.log("I'm here!");
           revert FundMe__FundAmountMustBeAboveZero();
      }
      doOtherStuff();
}`
What do you get in console? It is weird that it doesn't go inside `if` when value is 0. On the other hand you don't need `amount <= 0`, because `amount` is a `uint` type which can't be negative.

Comment: I get "amount:  0
I'm here!" as expected but like I said the issues are only happening on the testnet and not on the local hardhat network.

Comment: So test still says `AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted
      + expected - actual

      -Transaction NOT reverted.
      +Transaction reverted.` even your code goes into `if` statement and it's proven by console.logs? That's very, very weird.

Comment: No it doesn't say that when I test LOCALLY on the hardhat network. The tests pass locally and the console.logs are as expected, but on the Goerli Testnet (where I can't use console.logs as far as I know) it says transaction NOT reverted.

Comment: How? When I go to your transaction's link I see that it failed and transaction was reverted.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, it says in the test that it was not reverted, but by checking etherscan you can see that did in fact revert

Comment: I reproduced your contract and test and it works fine. I suggest you to create a new project from scratch and try again. Whole test looks that: `it("fails when you fund 0 tokens", async function () {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const fundMeContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("XXX");
    const fundMe = await fundMeContract.deploy();
    await fundMe.deployed();
    await expect(
      fundMe.fund(deployer.address, 0)
    ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(
      fundMe,
      "FundMe__FundAmountMustBeAboveZero"
    );
  });`

Comment: It would be tough to start from scratch because this is actually a pretty large contract but I was just showing this one small part of its functionality. I guess the issue must derive from elsewhere then. To confirm, you tried running that on the Goerli testnet?

Comment: No, only local test. It reverted as test assumes so it will do the same on any EVM.

Comment: Well for me I catch the revert locally but not on the actual chain, could you try that on your end by any chance? Running the test on a real testnet?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with ethereum-waffle 3.4.4
Update the package version to a recent one.
In my case it worked well with 4.0.7